# Unable to install/remove anything from Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

Whenever i am trying to install any package or trying to remove any existing package. i am facing below error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package mongodb-org-server needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go inside of  `/var/lib/apt/lists` and then find the package named contains **mongodb-org-server** then remove accordingly then run `sudo apt-get update`.

otherwise, run

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then `sudo apt-get update`. I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I already have tried it but unfortunately the solution is not working.

Comment: Is that package exists there at `/var/lib/apt/lists`

Comment: if it doesn't solve problem, you can refer https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/cannot-install-and-remove-package-847795/

Comment: inside the `/var/lib/apt/lists` dir there is no package of  **mongodb-org-server**